# Convert PG::Result to an Active Record model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

`pg-ruby` allows you to send multiple queries to the database in one shot, which helps minimize the number of trips made to the database:

```
results = []
conn.send_query('QUERY1;QUERY2;QUERY3')
conn.block
while result = conn.get_result
  results << result
end
```

Given that for any `result` I already know the Active Record model, what's the appropriate way to convert the result into models? Right now I'm doing the following:

```
fields = result.fields
models = result.values.map { |value_set| 
  Model.new(Hash[fields.zip(value_set)])
}
```

The problem with that method is that each of the Active Record objects don't appear to be `#persisted?` since they've been instantiated with `.new`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think what you want is the [`ActiveRecord::Base.instantiate`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L66) method. It will correctly handle the `new_record?`/`persisted?` issue, as well as finding the correct class for single-table inheritance.

For example:

```
fields = result.fields
models = result.values.map { |value_set| 
  Model.instantiate(Hash[fields.zip(value_set)])
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's looks like a hack but anyway

```
fields = result.fields
models = result.values.map { |value_set| 
  hash = Hash[fields.zip(value_set)]
  model = Model.new(hash)
  # some attributes may not be assigned i.e. id, created_at and updated_at
  # in that case you can assign them manually:
  # model.id = hash["id"] 
  model.instance_variable_set :@new_record, false
  model
}
```