# RoR: Execute SQL in controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

In RoR, in the controller, we can see lines as below:

```
def index
    @books = Book.all
end
```

How can the @books = Book.all be replaced by actual sql query like select * from book

I tried something like below but I did not get it to work:

```
def index
    sql = 'Select * from books'
    @books = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
end
```

In the browser, I am seeing this error message:

undefined method `title' for #Hash:0x00007f8dbae412f0

Comment: What doesn't work? What kind of Object do you want returned? You could use `exec_query` instead of `execute` but `execute` should work as well so...

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What do you try to achieve? This sounds like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284887) to me.

Comment: `connection.execute` doesn't return instances of ActiveRecord but a simple Hash. When you do not use Rails query language then you cannot expect to work with proper ActiveRecord model.

Comment: @spickermann, I remember I used to use actual query statement in Laravel and I might need to use it going forward in ROR.

Comment: Do you want to convert the result of the database to rails object? Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30826015/convert-pgresult-to-an-active-record-model

You want to use custom SQL? Take a look at find_by_sql:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#finding-by-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The find_by_sql method by Active Record is the way to go.

```
def index
    @books = Book.find_by_sql('Select * from books')
end
```

reference: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#finding-by-sql